# What is the correct expression for the word "dearth"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Should I say:

> There **are** no dearth of aspirants for this job.

(plural form)

or should I say:

> There **is** no dearth of aspirants for this job.

(singular form)

Which is the correct version?

Just one of those silly doubts which creep up while writing. :)

Comment: "Dearth" is singular, and it is the subject of your sentence.  Singular subject, singular verb.

Comment: Please do not just make up tags that you think fit.  If you seriously think we're missing a tag, please propose it in Meta and see what other people think.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @JRE and illustrated by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dearth#examples), the correct phrasing recognizes that *dearth* is singular:

> There *is* no dearth of aspirants for this job.
>
> ...a company-wide dearth of talent *is* the core reason his Chevy simply isn't as fast in 2005 as it's been in the past.

Is *dearth* always singular? [No](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dearths&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdearths%3B%2Cc0), and here's an example sentence:

> Recurring dearths of willing enlistees *have* whittled away at the army over the past few decades.

However, it sounds quite unnatural and would be better using different words.

Comment: However the dearths are recurring, there has only been one dearth at any given time so every time a dearth occurred the senior people would have said "There _is a_ dearth of applicants". In retrospect they may have said "There _were_ dearths of applicants in 2010, 2013 and 2015" but "There _was a_ dearth of applicants in 2015"